# Where does my commit goes if I checkout tag and commit?

Tags: git

In GIT, if I checkout a tag I'll get my working copy to that tag's reference, i.e. the code will represent what I had at that time. I'm I correct?

Now, if I do that, and modify my code and commit. Where is that commit going? Will it sort of 'auto-merge'? Meaning that if I push my commit, someone that clones the repo will also get the fix I did from the tag? Or otherwise, if I switch back to master, will I have the code modification available there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commit is still only stored locally.   Only you have a reference to the modified version.  If you want to make it available to others, you will also have to do a `git push` of your code to the given branch.

Your commits are branch-specific, meaning if you change branches after committing, your changes will not carry over.  However, when you change back to the branch, the commit will still be there.

Comment: Yes, I know I have to push it. But, when I do, where will it go? Say I push to 'remotes/origin/master'. This will be merged there?

Comment: ok, if I checkout from a tag, I should do it to a new branch. Then work my code, then merge it back to orgin/master then push it. Otherwise the fix will not carry over.

Comment: @code-gijoe Right, your code only pushes to wherever you have your upstream configured to be, or to whatever branch you specify.  If you push towards a branch, your code will only be available on that branch.  If you want the changes available in master, you will need to either push towards master, or merge the changes like you mentioned.

Comment: @code-gijoe "remotes/origin/master" is not something you push to. It is a marker in your local repository to represent the position of the branch named "master" in remote repository identified by "origin" in your local (again) configuration. So to answer your question: it will go to the remote repository. If the remote "master" was not changed since you pulled and modified it, it will be just updated to point to your commit. Otherwise, the `push` will be abort with an error, describing the problem

Comment: FWIW, you _can_ push into your local repository. Doesn't make much sense, since it is easier to update local references by just running `git update-ref`, but it is certainly possible: `git push . HEAD:foo`

Answer (score 2):

It will not "auto-merge". It is stored in the repository, referenced by HEAD directly. Usually the reference HEAD (the small file in .git, named HEAD) contains the name of the branch, which top-commit reference is updated with every commit. In you case it is a so called "detached HEAD".

You can always save the detached HEAD in a real branch reference: `git branch something`. Or just checkout another branch and forget about the commits, they will be cleaned up eventually.